# Google maps marker custom context menu

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to create a custom context menu for google maps that will only work if I click a marker but this context menu that I am using will display the context menu anywhere I click. I want to make the context menu specifically for the map marker.

HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>
<div class="menu" id="menu">
    <div class="menu-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Manage files</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function myMap() {
    var menuDisplayed = false;
    var menuBox = null;
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
    var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 5};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
    marker.setMap(map);
    window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function() {
        var left = arguments[0].clientX;
        var top = arguments[0].clientY;

        menuBox = document.getElementById("menu");
        menuBox.style.left = left + "px";
        menuBox.style.top = top + "px";
        menuBox.style.display = "block";

        arguments[0].preventDefault();

        menuDisplayed = true;
    }, false);
    window.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if(menuDisplayed == true){
            menuBox.style.display = "none"; 
        }
    }, true);

}
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    width: 150px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: grey;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}

.menu-item {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    background-color: #6CB5FF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be rather than capturing all the clicks on the `window` object, just capture `rightclick` on the marker, open your context menu, close it on clicks on the map.

```
marker.addListener("rightclick", function(e) {
  for (prop in e) {
    if (e[prop] instanceof MouseEvent) {
      mouseEvt = e[prop];
      var left = mouseEvt.clientX;
      var top = mouseEvt.clientY;

      menuBox = document.getElementById("menu");
      menuBox.style.left = left + "px";
      menuBox.style.top = top + "px";
      menuBox.style.display = "block";

      mouseEvt.preventDefault();

      menuDisplayed = true;
    }
  }
});
map.addListener("click", function(e) {
  if (menuDisplayed == true) {
    menuBox.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/v8pdugjq/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function myMap() {
  var menuDisplayed = false;
  var menuBox = null;
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 5
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
  marker.addListener("rightclick", function(e) {
    for (prop in e) {
      if (e[prop] instanceof MouseEvent) {
        mouseEvt = e[prop];
        var left = mouseEvt.clientX;
        var top = mouseEvt.clientY;

        menuBox = document.getElementById("menu");
        menuBox.style.left = left + "px";
        menuBox.style.top = top + "px";
        menuBox.style.display = "block";

        mouseEvt.preventDefault();

        menuDisplayed = true;
      }
    }

  });
  map.addListener("click", function(e) {
    if (menuDisplayed == true) {
      menuBox.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", myMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

.menu {
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}

.menu-item {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #6CB5FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <div class="menu-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Manage files</div>
</div>
```